# Nokogiri: Running into error "undefined method ‘text’ for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm a newbie to programmer so excuse my noviceness. So I'm using Nokogiri to scrape a police crime log. Here is the code below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.sfsu.edu/~upd/crimelog/index.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css("title").text
doc.css(".brief").each do |brief|
 puts brief.at_css("h3").text
end
```

I used the selector gadget bookmarklet to find the CSS selector for the log (.brief). When I pass "h3" through brief.at_css I get all of the h3 tags with the content inside.

However, if I add the .text method to remove the tags, I get NoMethod error.

Is there any reason why this is happening? What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify if you look at the structure of the HTML source you will see that the very first occurrence of `<div class="brief">` does not have a child `h3` tag (it actually only has a child `<p>` tag).

The [Nokogiri Docs](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) say that

> at_css(*rules)
>
> Search this node for the first occurrence of CSS rules. Equivalent to css(rules).first See Node#css for more information.

If you call `at_css(*rules)` the docs states it is equivalent to `css(rules).first`. When there are items (your `.brief` class contains a `h3`) then an `Nokogiri::XML::Element` object is returned which responds to `text`, whereas if your `.brief` does not contain a `h3` then a `NilClass` object is returned, which of course does not respond to `text`

So if we call `css(rules)` (not `at_css` as you have) we get a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` object returned, which has the `text()` method defined as (notice the `alias`)

```
# Get the inner text of all contained Node objects
  def inner_text
    collect{|j| j.inner_text}.join('')
  end
  alias :text :inner_text
```

because the class is `Enumerable` it iterates over it's children calling their `inner_text` method and joins them all together.

Therefore you can either perform a `nil?` check or as @floatless correctly stated just use the `css` method

Answer (score 4):

You just need to replace `at_css` with `css` and everything should be okay.

Comment: Except that `css` returns a NodeSet, where `at_css` returns a Node, so the NodeSet will need to be iterated over.

Comment: Except you can call #inner_text on a NodeSet too. Whether it will do what you want depends on what you want to happen when there are > 1 matches. If there are always only 0 or 1, it will probably do what you want.